# C# - How I can convert List to JSONObject

Tags: c#, json

How to convert `List<Friend>` to a `JSONObject`?

This is my list variable

```
public List<Friend> friends { get; set; }
```

I tried to convert with this

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(friends)
```

But I get this result

```
{
    "friends": "[
        {
            \"row\": \"value\",
            \"row\": \"value\",
            \"row\": \"value\"
        },
        {
            \"row\": \"value\",
            \"row\": \"value\",
            \"row\": \"value\"
        }
    ]"
}
```

I want it like this

```
{
    "friends": {
        {
            "row": "value",
            "row": "value",
            "row": "value"
        },
        {
            "row": "value",
            "row": "value",
            "row": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a third party library, e.g. [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { friends = friends });
```

Comment: it's the escape characters showing up in the debugger, dude you don't need to worry about it

Comment: @CanSpielt If you write the serialized string to file (e.g. with `File.WriteAllText`), can you still see them?

Comment: `{
   "friends":[
      {
         "publicname":"null",
         "username":"Testeeer",
         "status":"null",
         "timestamp":"123456789",
         "online":false,
         "profilepicture":"null"
      },
      {
         "publicname":"null",
         "username":"Testeeer",
         "status":"null",
         "timestamp":"123456789",
         "online":false,
         "profilepicture":"null"
      }
   ]
}`

Comment: The `[ ]` chars indicate that it is an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) (in JSON - in your C# code it is a List).

Comment: And how I can convert back the string to `JSONObject` in java? With the `[ ]` chars I get the exception `.. cannot to converted to a JSONObject`

Comment: Java? I thought you were using C#? In any case, look for `JSONArray`.

Comment: Yes, i use C# for the server and java for my android application.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more simple to just call `Replace` after serializing it:

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(friends).Replace(@"\""", @"""");
```

I hope this helps you, please bear with me if the above does not work properly,  as I'm on my mobile now (and I can't really test at the moment). It should be clear that you have to call `Replace` on the `string` variable you've posted, so it might be possible that I'm missing a `ToString()` somewhere in my code.

But as I can see, you know how to get the string, so please call `Replace` after it and it works fine.

Comment: I've needed some time to type my answer..  :D When I started, there was no answer there.  :/ I also use json.NET in my project. Anyway mine works without any 3rd party libs...